# Undefined index: when put ajax Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i have this function upload on codeigniter, it works fine without ajax validation

here is the controller

```
  public function upload_pdf(){

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('DOC_NAME',  'Document Name'    ,'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('DOC_TYPE',  'Document Type'    ,'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('DOC_DATE',  'Date'             ,'trim|required');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile', 'Document', 'callback_pdf_upload');

    if($this->form_validation->run($this) == TRUE){

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile', 'Document', 'callback_pdf_upload2');

      if($this->form_validation->run($this) == TRUE){

        $file_data = $this->upload->data();
        $url = base_url().'uploads/pdf/'.$file_data['file_name'];
        $this->PDFuploads_Model->insert($url);
        $this->index();

      }else{

        $this->add_view();

      }//second validation

    }else{

      $this->add_view();
    }// first

  }// end function


  public function pdf_upload(){


    if($_FILES['userfile']['size'] != 0){

      return true;

    }else{

      $this->form_validation->set_message('pdf_upload', "<p class='text-danger'><i class='  fa fa-times-circle-o' ></i> No file selected</p>");
      return false;
    }// end if else
  }
```

but when i make it a ajax validation file i got the error `Severity: Notice --> Undefined index: userfile`

on this line

`if($_FILES['userfile']['size'] != 0){`

my controller looks like this when i make it ajax validation

```
  public function upload_pdf(){

    $data = array('success' => false, 'messages' => array());

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('DOC_NAME',  'Document Name'    ,'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('DOC_TYPE',  'Document Type'    ,'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('DOC_DATE',  'Date'             ,'trim|required');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile', 'Document', 'callback_pdf_upload');

    if($this->form_validation->run($this) == TRUE){

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile', 'Document', 'callback_pdf_upload2');

      $data['success'] = true;

      if($this->form_validation->run($this) == TRUE){

        $file_data = $this->upload->data();
        $url = base_url().'uploads/pdf/'.$file_data['file_name'];
        $this->PDFuploads_Model->insert($url);
        $data['success'] = true;

      }else{

        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
          # code...
          $data['messages'][$key] = form_error($key);
        }

      }//second validation

    }else{

      foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        # code...
        $data['messages'][$key] = form_error($key);
      }

    }// first
    echo json_encode($data);
  }// end function
```

**take note** that it works fine without the ajax, but when i put ajax **`Severity: Notice --> Undefined index: userfile`** becomes an error

AJAX CODE IS

```
  $('#form-user').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var me = $(this);

    // perform ajax
    $.ajax({
      url: me.attr('action'),
      type: 'post',
      data: me.serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) {
        if (response.success == true) {
          // if success we would show message
          // and also remove the error class
          $('#the-message').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' +
            '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>' +
            ' Data has been saved' +
            '</div>');
          $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error')
                  .removeClass('has-success');
          $('.text-danger').remove();

          // reset the form
          me[0].reset();

          // close the message after seconds
          $('.alert-success').delay(500).show(10, function() {
            $(this).delay(3000).hide(10, function() {
              $(this).remove();
            });
          })
        }
        else {
          $.each(response.messages, function(key, value) {
            var element = $('#' + key);

            element.closest('div.form-group')
            .removeClass('has-error')
            .addClass(value.length > 0 ? 'has-error' : '')
            .find('.text-danger')
            .remove();

            element.after(value);
          });
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Can you show us your AJAX code?

Comment: @ShrikantMavlankar I already updated it bro